# Accessing Intel J4125 GPIO Pins

Tags: drivers

Does anyone knows how to access and write to the Intel J4125 board GPIO? I have tried using the raspberrypi GPIO tools and it cannot detect the hardware pins. I have tired to load the gpio-it87 module and the gpiochip0 shows up (using gpiodetect) but I am unable to change the pin values, meaning using gpioset (gpioset 0 0=0 or gpioset 0 0=1) writing a 1 or 0 changes nothing because the read (gpioget 0 0) always return 1. I have also tried to load all the other gpio-* modules using modprode but only gpio-it87 creates a gpiochip960 directory under /sys/class/gpio. I am running ubuntu 20.04 and I also tried 22.04.2 LTS [Board setup for the GPIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA7Yl.jpg)